# conditionalizing text for html output

Tags: doxygen

What would be best way to conditionalize text (not code).
There are 3 levels of documentation that I want conditionalized and tagged as:
**Developer** – This would be documentation that I don’t want doxygen to output at all. Such as notes to developers.
**Internal** – Information visible only for internal versions of documentation.
**NDA** - Information for customers plus anything not tagged as Developer or Internal; a subset of the Internal docs and would filter out internal websites for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of doxygen commands and configuration options which will help you achieve this. These include [`\internal`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinternal) and `\endinternal`. From the doxygen manual:

> `\internal` This command starts a documentation fragment that is meant for internal use only.
>
> You can use `INTERNAL_DOCS` in the config file to show (`YES`) or hide (`NO`) the internal documentation.

To address the three versions of documentation you want:

- **Developer**: Use standard C/C++ comments, `/* ... */`. These won't be touched by doxygen.
- **Internal**: For documentation only for internal use, use doxygen comments, `/** ... */`, and wrap these parts of the documentation with the `\internal` and `\endinternal` commands. When distributing the documentation internally set the configuration file option `INTERNAL_DOCS` to `YES` when building the documentation.
- **NDA**: For documentation visable to the customer simply use doxygen comments `/** ... */` and set the configuration option`INTERNAL_DOCS` to `NO` in the configuration file when building the documentation.